# Where can i find a pre-computed 8 caracter uppercase password file/dictionary

Tags: password-cracking, hashcat

To create an all permutations dictionary of an 8 character uppercase only password, I get I can use crunch to make this wordlist and file would roughly be 1.8 - 2Tb in size.

Is there anywhere I can download this file but already pre-computed to allow me to crack the password faster?

E.g I get 4200 k/s using my crunch wordlist which is not pre-computed.
If its possible to have this pre-computed...will this allow my computer to test the pre-computed keys faster compared to non pre-computed wordlist?

Comment: What are you asking exactly? What are you breaking? A hash? An encryption key?  A website? If hash, What kind of hash? Is there salt? If key, what encryption? What key derivation function? Need more info.

Comment: Its my sky router password. Most default sky router passwords are 8 uppcase caracters only. 26*8

Comment: Do you have a hash to crack and can you calculate hashes of that type faster than you can generate passwords? Is your internet connection fast enough that it's faster than you can generate passwords? Would the server hosting the file have the bandwidth to send it that fast? This seems almost certainly not worth it.

Comment: @SupaLemonHaze I'm very sure downloading your password list is NOT faster than locally generating it with some loops.

Comment: Sorry...im not explaining myself enough. Ive created wordlist of 8 upper before using crunch. I then tried using this wordlist to crack my router password. I see how this is pointless as i could brute force and do the same this given the right commands but i tried this because i thought testing keys from a wordlist would be faster than bruteforce intself. So anyway what asking may not be possible.

Comment: Maybe i havent grasped the concept of wordlists and pre computed hashes etc

Comment: I'd rather not download it if i could create it nyself but how to compute the wordlist so that it cracks fast keys per second if possible

Comment: Ok after some quick research on the topic, which i should have done before hand. I now know a bit more on hashes etc.

Comment: So my question now....what does pre computed mean/do ? Inregards to passwords/hashes ? And how it differs from non pre computed. Thanks

Comment: the whole point of wordlists, and the reason they make attacks faster, is that they are NOT brute force rainbow tables, they are humanly weak patterns that are more likely used than mere permutations.

Comment: Really appreciate all the feed back guys. Guess i thought it was easier than it is, but in that case passwords would be useless. I would use popular word lists but as my router default password is 8 uppercase caracters only, you can see using for e.g RockYou wordlist wouldnt find a match. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with the comments in mind, your use-case probably can't benefit from using pre-computed wordlist. Pre-computed wordlists as described help in cases where you have a hash of the password or in case you need a (slowly derived) key from the password using something like PBKDF2 or BCrypt.

In case of a login to a website or a router, there is nothing to pre-compute as you are sending the plain-text password to the router and the site/router is checking the password on its own (and potentially hashing it, but you can't send it a hash, it has to do it itself). Therefore there is no way you can use any sort of a list or file to accelerate the guessing.